# Can't create new gauge project with VSCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, getgauge

I'm trying to configure Gauge with VS Code integration but when I try to execute the command

> Gauge: Create new Gauge Project

I get the error

> *command gauge.createProject not found*

.

I've followed the getting stared guide from: https://gauge.org/getting-started-guide/we-start/.

- installed gauge
- installed Gauge VSCode extension

I was able to create a C# gauge project from (windows) command line and successfully execute the example spec but when I try from VSCode command it always fails.

It seems that maybe I've missed some step in the configuration but I'cant figure out what. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?
Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

I exactly had the same issue when installing gauge extension version 0.0.12 to vscode . Downgrading to one version down worked great. I succeed to created a gauge python new project .